# Control table width with Jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question regarding the IE7

I want to make every column of my table has the same width no matter what contents they have

```
 $("table").each(function(){
        var column =0;

        var totalWidth = $(this).width();
        $('tr:nth-child(1) td',this).each(function(){
            column ++;
        })

        var cellWidth = totalWidth / column;
        $('td', this).css('width', cellWidth);
    })
```

My codes work perfect on chrome and FF but not IE 7. I am not sure why. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you specify UNITS px? em? watermelons per second?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? jquery 2.x supports IE9+. http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: @Diodeus watermelons per second? I think you meant to say [`Gallaghers`](http://tvrecappersanonymous.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/gallagher-sledgeomatic.gif) :)

Comment: @Diodeus I tried cellWidth +'px' but it is still not working.

Comment: you can just do `var column = $('tr:first td',this).length;` instead of looping and manually counting the columns

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ, I have a similiar issue. Can we Skype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nth-child` is CSS3 selector and does not supported by IE 7. Try something else.

Comment: is :first supported in IE7?  This was the track I was going down, too.  +1

Comment: nth-child is supported as a jQuery selector though and will work in IE7 right?

Comment: Richard, yes, IE7 can work with ":first", but only if web-page has declarated doctype.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just put a class on all of your columns and then set it in CSS? That is just a waste of jQuery code.

```
<td class="col">...</td>
```

Then...

```
.col {
    width: 50px;
}
```

Or if you need it to be a certain percent of the page/table...

```
.col {
    width: 20%;   /* if 5 columns in the table, make each 20% of table width */
}
```

Comment: The problem is I have dynamic data and I don't know how many cell and what kind of contents I have.

Answer (score 1):

Set the table's [table-layout](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp) to

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

and provide a width shouldn't need jquery then

Comment: The problem is I have dynamic data and I don't know how many cell and what kind of contents I have.